# What is the SQL/JDBC equivalent to JPA merge API? What does it exactly do?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm migrating JPA api's like persist,save,merge,refresh,detach and remove to plain SQL using JDBC, where iam finding it hard to understand the concept of EntityManager.merge(someTask).

I tried a SQL **update** query for the merge API but the explanation of merge is as follows **Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence context**.But with plain SQL and JDBC its hard to understand how to do the same and i need to handle OptimisticLock as well.

The entity class which is used for JPA is as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK", indexes = {@Index(name = "RIO", columnList = "priority", unique = false),
@Index(name = "EXP", columnList = "expiry", unique = false), 
@Index(name = "STA", columnList = "taskStatus", unique = false),
@Index(name = "CAT", columnList = "category", unique = false),
@Index(name = "NEXTTRY", columnList = "nextTry", unique = false)})

public class TaskEntity {

@Version
private int version;

@Basic
@Column(length = Integer.MAX_VALUE, columnDefinition = "varchar(" + Integer.MAX_VALUE + ")")
private String taskId;

@Basic
private String category;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "KEY")
@CollectionTable(name = "TASKPROPERTIES", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                 name = "TASK_ID_FK",
                 foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (TASKENTITY_ID) REFERENCES TASK (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE"))

@Column(length = Integer.MAX_VALUE, columnDefinition = "varchar(" + Integer.MAX_VALUE + ")")
private Map<String, String> TaskProperties;

@Basic
@Column(length = Integer.MAX_VALUE, columnDefinition = "varchar(" + Integer.MAX_VALUE + ")")
private String destination;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TaskStatus taskStatus;

@Basic
private String type;

@Basic
private Long expiry;

@Basic
private Long nextTry;

@Basic
private Integer retries;

@Basic
private Integer priority;

//Setters and Getters
//Equals and HashCode

}
```

Hence what would be the equivalent of EntityManger.merge(task) to SQL/HSQL.

Comment: JPA's `merge` is a concept which does not exist absence the presence of an entity manager and detached entities.

Comment: Any information about the SQL equivalent of merge would be great :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Merge**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) in essence is the process of merging an existing record in a table with what has been provided in the statement (i.e. **UPDATE** if the record exists else **INSERT**). Also known as [`UPSERT`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)#Synonymous).

Let us say you have a table tbl_person that has primary key person_ssn and two other columns namely name and age. In case you want to insert a statement on a person_ssn  that happens to exist there, DBs will throw error. Your requirement is to insert a record if the person_ssn doesn't exist else update the name and age. In such situation you will use **Merge**.

There are few ways to achieve this, two of them are

1. Issue at least two DML statements. First do a **SELECT** on the person_ssn and based on whether you found a record, subsequently, you will either issue an **UPDATE** or an **INSERT** statement
2. Use **MERGE** SQL statement. This is the more modern and direct way but not all databases support it. Read more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)). Further, just to get an idea, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), on how MERGE SQL statement works in SQL Server which supports it

As far as Java JPA is concerned, implementations abstract this concept. Depending on DB's support for MERGE SQL statement, either it is used or two statements (SELECT followed by either UPDATE or INSERT) are issued to accomplish the same.

hsqldb offers MERGE SQL support as per comment provided.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.Merge seems to work with HSQLDB :-). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074694/upserting-a-row-into-an-hsqldb-table-using-the-merge-sql-statement

Comment: @chetan: no need to guess. It's fully documented: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement

Comment: Got my Answer:-)

Comment: [This page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) discusses how `INSERT … ON CONFLICT` works in Postgres, and compares the implementations of other database systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to merge semantically (in case of ORM context) other than just `upsert`. Essentially your entity model is a graph of objects having relations to each other using memory pointers. The objective of merge API is to enable reflecting the expected future state of object graph with the current state. Typically the ORM would issue SQL insert/updates/deletes to reflect the expected future state and not necessarily SQL MERGE. For e.g., the future entity state has a one to many relation as null - this would result in ORM issuing query to nullify the foreign key in the child table to reflect this state. In nutshell - when you pass an object ( which is a graph of interconnected objects) to merge , the ORM first determines for individual objects whether they need to be newly persisted or if they contain identifier of already persisted data then load them into persistence context ( if not already there) and apply all data changes and relationship updates. Finally the dirty checking mechanism of ORM makes sure to generate equivalent SQL to reflect this final state.

> EntityManager - merge(T entity)      Merge the state of the given entity into the
>   current persistence context.